# No se producen resultados con la orden LIKE desde Android

Tags: java, mysql, android-studio

Desde Android Studio realizo la siguiente consulta contra una base de datos MySQL

```
 SELECT id_ave,
       Date_format(fch_ave, '%d/%m/%Y') AS 'fecha',
       zon_ave,
       cli_ave,
       per_ave,
       tip_ave,
       Ifnull(nom_tip_ave, 'Sin tipo')  AS 'tipos',
       est_ave,
       pri_ave,
       des_ave,
       img_ave,
       Ifnull(nom_zon, 'Sin zona')      AS 'zonas',
       Ifnull(nom_cli, 'Sin cliente')   AS 'clientes',
       Ifnull(nom_est, 'Sin estado')    AS 'estados'
FROM   (((ctrl_averias
          LEFT JOIN ctrl_zonas
                 ON ctrl_averias.zon_ave = ctrl_zonas.id_zon)
         LEFT JOIN ctrl_clientes
                ON ctrl_averias.cli_ave = ctrl_clientes.id_cli)
        LEFT JOIN ctrl_tipos_averias
               ON ctrl_averias.tip_ave = ctrl_tipos_averias.id_tip_ave)
       LEFT JOIN ctrl_estados
              ON ctrl_averias.est_ave = ctrl_estados.id_est
WHERE  ( nom_cli LIKE '%afa%' )
ORDER  BY pri_ave DESC,
          est_ave ASC
```

El problema está que, tras varias pruebas, he comprobado que la consulta funciona bien si le quito `%af` al principio del *like*.

Hay datos que cuadran con el patrón y se que la consulta es muy engorrosa, pero es que tengo que recuperar toda esa información de golpe. Me parece que el problema está en la codificación (ya que para el webservice) de la consulta utilizo el charset 'utf8mb4', recomendado en otro mensaje de este foro.

Por favor, ayuda!!!!!!

Comment: Amigo es más fácil que consumas un SP a que hagas la consulta desde la aplicación. Es una opción.

Answer (score 1):

Comentas que obtienes resultados si eliminas `%af` de:

```
nom_cli LIKE '%afa%'
```

lo que sucede en realidad es que no hay algún registro que tenga el texto "afa" en el campo `nom_cli`.

Realiza una impresión de todos los registros y busca si alguno tiene en el campo     `nom_cli` el texto "afa" para que compruebes lo que comento.

Comment: Si los hay, pero es como si rechazase los dos primeros caracteres, me pasa igual con otro cliente es "Bar Cervecería Los Patios", donde si busco por `%bar%` o `%Bar%` no hay ningún resultado, pero si escribo `%cerve%` si se producen.

Comment: He quitado el primer símbolo de tanto por ciento % del like y funciona a la perfección, pero cuando añado el like de la forma `%texto_a_buscar%` ya no funciona.